# On MacOS, how can I search/browse in some process's memory?

Tags: grep, process, memory, macos

I'm using MacOS X 10.7 and I'm not very familiar with unix. Is there a command for a search in some process's memory for a string?

Comment: Reminds me of the "Artmoney" tool I used to cheat in games on Windows :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Mac OSX does not have a /proc file system.  On other species of unix the /proc filesystem should have an entry for each running process named with the corresponding pid.  The memory space of the process would be available through `/proc/${pid}/mem` to root or any user with appropriate permissions.

I believe system calls are available that do much of this.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6949866/contents-of-a-programs-memory-mac/6951484#6951484) is to a stackoverflow posting where the author has written a utility that dumps the memory image of a process to disk.  It might do what you want.